# Could the Daughter attain the ability to retain consciousness after death?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

Part of the conversation between Yoda and Qui-Gon Jinn when the latter explained the ability to become one with the Force yet retain consciousness (henceforth called the Force ghost ability) goes as follows:

> Yoda: "Eternal life…"
> Qui-Gon: "The ultimate goal of the Sith, yet they can never achieve it; it comes only through the release of self, not the exaltation of self. It comes through compassion, not greed. Love is the answer to the darkness."

It has also been revealed that Anakin Skywalker was able to redeem himself and attain this ability when he finally defeated the darkness within him and willingly sacrificed himself to save his son out of pure selfless love.

The Daughter is an enigmatic and extremely powerful Force-sensitive, an embodiment of the light side and believed by some to be of godlike status or nearly so. This suggests that she is most probably capable of becoming a Force ghost - which can be considered to be the pinnacle of the light side - as well. After all, she has also sacrificed herself for love, in her case to save the Father from the Son.

Theoretically, it seems all the conditions are met as far as I can see: she did the same thing as Anakin did to qualify to learn the ability, and her proficiency in the light side is undeniably far beyond Yoda or Obi-Wan's. Did she actually go on to become a "Force ghost" though? There are speculations that she is

> the Convor in *Star Wars Rebels*

but nothing is confirmed. Are there any other sources not mentioned that can help to answer this question or identify the likeliest outcome?

Comment: The color scheme similarity *is* striking.

Comment: I’m not totally sure she *did* die. I was watching some commentary by Filoni, and the impression I got is that the whole experience with the Ones was very spiritual, perhaps even a vision (it’s compared to a similar vision that Luke had in the original trilogy). So the Daughter might not have died at all, in a sense. She might never have had quite what one would call a physical existence.

Comment: My thoughts ventured as far as to say she had always been one with the Force - and thus already attained the ability - from the beginning, but that appears to be moot considering the Son should be of the same nature yet should be incapable of being so in theory. Then again, I always assumed they actually existed and aren't merely a manifestation of the Force itself to serve its will, perhaps because of the influence of Legends where they did exist as a real physical being.

Comment: Yes, I think they are likely to be revealed as manifestations of aspects of the Force in the new canon. There was always a hint of that in the original arc, in any case. The manifestations can have consciousness, perhaps, but the Force is larger than they. But we shall see.

Answer (score 0):

From what I’ve read in the Fate of the Jedi books, the Killiks describe the Ones as Celestials with a solid form. The Killiks say they formed out of a geyser eruption, though it’s worth noting that the Killik’s take anything in the hive-mind as true. My theory is that you can’t kill a Celestial, merely dissipate the Ones. It’s worth mentioning that the Brother and the Sister gained power from the Well of Power and Pool of Knowledge, respectively. Since none of the Ones were truly killed, my guess is that for The Daughter to have made a physical form would have child’s play. As to why The Brother didn’t make one, I don’t know, though my guess for The Father was that he would have an extremely frail form (hence why he was trying to get Anakin to replace him). I know there’s no quotes, but I’m 99% sure that’s what they say in the Fate of the Jedi series, when they ask for what a One is and where Abeloth came from.

Summary

Ones are extremely powerful. The Pool of Knowledge (which boosted the Daughter’s powers) wasn’t destroyed, so she could still draw on it’s power to make the Convor. That’s my theory atleast.